# Removing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from a dual boot setup and recovering the Windows boot manager

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows 7 Home Premium on my laptop. My desire is to uninstall Ubuntu without spoiling MBR and Windows 7.

I would like to emphasize that Ubuntu was installed later so I select the OS in GRUB. I would also like to uninstall GRUB. How can I do so in a painless and simple manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows you can use ["Dual-boot Repair"](http://www.boyans.net) tool. 
Rewrite all partition boot records and MBR.

**Or** from Windows 7 recovery/installation CD/DVD/USB run on command prompt:

**bootsect  /nt60  ALL  /mbr**

**Or** you could just run "StartUp Repair" from Windows 7 recovery CD.
Eventually you have to run StartUp Repair more then once with rebooting after each run to check if problem is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like the following steps if I were you:

1. Backup any valuable data on your Ubuntu system
2. Boot into a Windows 7 installation disc
3. Repair your system by overwriting the MBR (Master Boot Record)
4. Boot into Windows 7
5. Format the Ubuntu partition(s)

By overwriting the MBR and formatting the Ubuntu partition(s) you are effectively "uninstalling" GRUB and Ubuntu, although there's no such thing as uninstalling them - only writing over previous data.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds worth trying. Why I cannot erase GRUB, isn't there an option to do so?

Comment: @Vesnog Overwriting the MBR *is* erasing GRUB because GRUB lives there. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#Booting.

Comment: Okay, I understood now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EasyBCD for safely uninstall.

Comment: In which OS should I use this program?